# webapi data convert into another language

Tags: android, json, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I am creating cross platform  application using xamarin forms  which display some data like following into the list view.

if user change their own language to Hindi,Spanish  or Turkish  then this list should be display into the Hindi, Spanish  or Turkish

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

how can i convert it from one language to another language.

Comment: In what way you would like to "convert" the list? Shouldn't you just recall the API with an additional param like `?lang=es`?

Comment: i am sharing with you my api url.. [link](http://web.rpc.project.it-hub.org/api/countries ) can you please guide me how to add? lang=es or ?lang=fr or ?lang=es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Google translation services i can translate the object data in to 64 Languages.

Sample Code: 
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html

Languages Support:
http://ctrlq.org/code/19899-google-translate-languages#languages